# Error while inserting the recordsCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, foreign-keys

I have created tables in MYSQL as follows

Author Table

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
`AuthorId` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`AuthorName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AuthorId`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Books Table

```
 CREATE TABLE `books` (
 `DocId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ISBN` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`DocId`),
 KEY `DocId` (`DocId`),
 CONSTRAINT `books_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DocId`) REFERENCES `document` 
 (`DocId`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Document Table

```
 CREATE TABLE `document` (
 `DocId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `PublishDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `AuthorId` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DocType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`DocId`),
 KEY `AuthorId` (`AuthorId`),    
 CONSTRAINT `document_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`AuthorId`) REFERENCES `author` 
 (`AuthorId`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I made a server for my PHP website on XAMPP and am using mysql but when I try inserting the values in Document table I get

```
error while inserting the recordsCannot add or update a child row: a foreign 
key constraint fails (`librarydb`.`document`, CONSTRAINT `document_ibfk_3` 
FOREIGN KEY (`AuthorId`) REFERENCES `author` (`AuthorId`))
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: the lengths/NULLorNOT NULL missmatch between `author.AuthorId` and `document.AuthorId`

Comment: and while you're at it: ask yourself if 'AuthorId' really needs to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked fields `author.AuthorId` and `document.AuthorId` are not defined the same way.
[From the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same.

So make them both varchar(10) NOT NULL - or whatever you need.